# How to fixJSON_PARSING_ERROR: Unexpected character?

Tags: python, json, django, python-requests

I'm using Django to send notifications to android users and [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library to handle the post request. This is my code snippet where I send the actual request to FCM.

```
def sendNotification(rule_name):

    url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"
    headers = {'Authorization': '********************',
               'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    myDict = {"to": "/topics/rules",
              "data": {
                        "rule_name": rule_name
                      }
              }
    r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=myDict)
    print r.status_code
    print r.text
```

However the response that I get when I print the status code and text is:

**400
JSON_PARSING_ERROR: Unexpected character (t) at position 0.**

Can you please point out what is wrong here with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you do something like this?

```
import json
r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(myDict))
```